# Uncaught TypeError, innerHTML of null error at random when target string is too long

Tags: javascript, typeerror

I'm getting this error when trying to use `innerHTML` to `console.log` the contents of the `p` tag with the `comment` class, the first three always work. But it only happens sometimes, seemingly at random. The only pattern I've noticed is it always works when the string is 50 characters or shorter.

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'innerHTML' of null at HTMLDivElement.card.addEventListener (<anonymous>:90:59)`

I tried using `getElementsByClassName("card")[0]` instead of `querySelector(".card")`, but that had the same result. Also, I can't use an ID in this case because I have an unknown number of `card` elements on the page.

HTML:

```
<div class="card">
    <input type="checkbox" hidden />
    <div>
        <div>
            <p class="mini-card date">Fri, 07 Sept</p>
            <p class="mini-card length">20 mins</p>
            <p class="mini-card type">Practice session</p>
        </div>
        <p class="comment">This text is 50 characters loooooooooooooooooooong</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
var cards = document.querySelectorAll(".card");
        Array.from(cards).forEach(card => {
            card.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
                console.log(event.target.querySelector(".date").innerHTML);
                console.log(event.target.querySelector(".length").innerHTML);
                console.log(event.target.querySelector(".type").innerHTML);
                console.log(event.target.querySelector(".comment").innerHTML);
            });
        });
```

Any help would be extremely helpful, thanks!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would have to see a working example to be sure, but I believe what happens when it throws an error is that you are clicking directly on the innermost div element. Since ".comment" is not a child of said element, querySelector returns null.

To get consistent results you could use [Event.currentTarget](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/currentTarget) instead of Event.target, as that will always point to the element to which you attached your event handler (in this case div class="card")

Answer (score 0):

Solution: check below

```js
var cards = document.querySelectorAll(".card");
Array.from(cards).forEach(card => { 
    var data = {
      date: card.querySelector(".date").innerHTML,
      length: card.querySelector(".length").innerHTML,
      type: card.querySelector(".type").innerHTML,
      comment: card.querySelector(".comment").innerHTML
    }
    card.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
          console.log(data)
    });
});
```

```html
<div class="card">
    <input type="checkbox" hidden />
    <div>
        <div onclick="">
            <p class="mini-card date">Fri, 07 Sept</p>
            <p class="mini-card length">20 mins</p>
            <p class="mini-card type">Practice session</p>
        </div>
        <p class="comment">This text is 50 characters loooooooooooooooooooongeeeeerrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrr</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

explanation:
It has nothing to do with length, but has everything to do with target. your event handler fires even when a child element is clicked. If you call query selector, it wont be able to find the sibling of the other element. which happens to be happening with your case.

enjoy